# FunctionCompile Type Errors

Tags: data-types, function-compile

This function works uncompiled:

```
Function[{n, m, k},
 ParallelSum[
  Length[Permutations[i]],
  {i, IntegerPartitions[m, {n}, Range[0, k]]}
 ]]
```

but compiling with `"Integer8"` fails:

```
FunctionCompile[
 Function[{
   Typed[n, "Integer8"],
   Typed[m, "Integer8"],
   Typed[k, "Integer8"]},
  ParallelSum[
   Length[Permutations[i]],
   {i, IntegerPartitions[m, {n}, Range[0, k]]}
  ]]]
```

The error says

> Message: Cannot find a definition for the function ParallelSum that takes 2 arguments.
> Tag: TypeError

Replacing with `Sum` fixes this but gives another error:

> Message: Cannot find a definition for the function IntegerPartitions that takes arguments with the types Integer8, PackedArray[Integer64, 1:Integer64] and PackedArray[Integer64, 1:Integer64].
> Tag: TypeError

Why does `ParallelSum` not take two arguments when `Sum` and uncompiled version do? `IntegerPartitions` not accepting integers or integer arrays when the uncompiled version works is also confusing.

Comment: I think you will not gain anything from compiling your code anyway. ParallelSum is a "KernelFunction" (you can declare it as so) but the only thing the compiled version will do is to call back to the interpreter.

Generally FunctionCompile does not support compiling arbitrary pieces of Mathematica code (for now) AFAIK

Comment: ah that's unfortunate; uncompiled evaluations for even n=20, m=20, k=10 proved extremely slow. hopefully future versions address this; thanks for the heads up